# Can't Scroll With Scrapy-Playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I'm only getting the initial links. The screenshot is always the same no matter what PageMethod I try. I've tried "keyboard.press", "mouse.wheel", etc. I've also read the docs and instead of using the PageMethod, added them to the parse method with still no luck.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import asyncio


class YtspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ytspider"
    

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.tiktok.com/@huberman.clips', meta={
            'playwright':True,
            'playwright_include_page': True,
            'playwright_page_methods': [
                PageMethod('wait_for_load_state','networkidle'),
                PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div.tiktok-16ou6xi-DivTagCardDesc.eih2qak1'),
                PageMethod('evaluate', "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                
                
                

            ],
                
            },
            errback= self.close_page
            )

    async def parse(self, response):
        try:
            page = response.meta['playwright_page']

            await page.screenshot(path="test.png", full_page=True)
            html = await page.content()
            

            s = Selector(text=html)
            for container in s.css('div.tiktok-16ou6xi-DivTagCardDesc.eih2qak1'):
                link = container.css('a::attr(href)').get()
                yield {
                    'link': link
                }
            await page.close()
        except Exception as e:
            self.log(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            await self.close_page(e)
```

Comment: Missing closing bracket: `PageMethod('evaluate', 'window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight')`

Change to...
`PageMethod('evaluate', "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

Comment: thank you. i've corrected that, but still having same issue

Comment: Please provide the updated code in the post as an [edit]. You can format it with [Black](https://black.vercel.app/) for easy comprehension.